# "jre-8u111-windows-x64.exe is not a valid win32 application"

Tags: java, windows

jre and jdk 32bi installs

jdk 64bit installs

jre 64bit gives "jre-8u111-windows-x64.exe is not a valid win32 application"

laptop is 64bit win7

have tried turning off firewall and antivirus, but still will not install.

what is keeping jre 64bit from installing on 64bit computer?

how to get jre to install in 64bit win7

what is causing jre 64bit to throw "jre-8u111-windows-x64.exe is not a valid

win32 application", when other 64bit programs will install?

Comment: you should try run it on compatibility mode  and by the way i think your OS is 32bit but the display is modified so you see your os as 64bit you can see if your os is actually 64bit if you saw that there are two folder windows the 64 and the normal so its 64bit but if you actually see only one the normal window folder it is 32bit

Comment: format your text properly

Comment: If you are sure your system is 64bit, maybe your jre installer is corrupted. Did you try to download it again?

Comment: Start by checking the simplest things first.  The most likely cause is that the download is corrupted, try downloading it again.

Answer (score 0):

harry johnston, i think you have the answer. downloaded a different jre and redownloaded eclipse. jre installed and eclipse is installing